# Evaluating a flux integral by the use of divergence theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> The sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=25$ is intersected by the plane $z=3$. The smaller portion forms a solid V bounded by a closed surface $S_0$ made up of two parts, a spherical part $S_1$ and a planar part $S_2$. Let $n=(\cos\alpha,\cos\beta,\cos\gamma$) denote the unit normal. Evaluate the surface integral:
>
> $\int \int (xz.\cos\alpha+yz.\cos\beta+\cos\gamma)dS$ if S is the spherical cap $S_1$.

I have an attempt, but my response doesn't match $144\pi$:

We have that $F(x,y,z)=(xz,yz,1)$. So, div F = $2z$. Using the divergence theorem, we have the following equality:

$ I = \int \int F\cdot dS = \int \int \int (2z)dxdydz$

Transforming this integral into spherical coordinates, we have:

$I= \int \int \int (2p^3\cos\varphi \sin\varphi)d\varphi d\theta dp$

The limits of integration shall be the following:

$0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi, 0\leq p \leq 5, \cos^{-1}(3/5) \leq \varphi \leq \pi$ .

Evaluating the integral I find $-200\pi$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using $0\le\varphi\le\cos^{-1}(3/5)$?

Comment: The spherical coordinate normally goes from $0 \leq \varphi \leq \pi$, right?. So, going from 0 to $cos^{-1}(3/5)$ takes only the part that is cut off by the plane. In reality we must go from $cos^{-1}(3/5)$ to $\pi $.

Comment: The use of divergence theorem doesn't call for any normal.

Comment: @math.h that impossible since you get + or - sign depending on which normal you choose. Ops, Ive deleted comment before, but you have $\iint (\vec{F} \cdot \vec{n}) dS$ there. Or am I just underslept?

Comment: Apostol's convention is the unit outer normal to S.

Comment: Can we use the divergence theorem for S1? S1 is the upper cap of the circle and it’s not a closed surface.

Answer (score 0):

In spherical coordinates, $z=r\cos\phi =3$, so $r=\frac{3}{\cos \phi}$. Also, the plane and the sphere intersect when $z=\rho\cos\phi=3$ and $\rho=5$, which gives $\phi=\cos^{-1}\frac{3}{5}$.

So the bounds should be
$$
0\le \theta \le 2\pi, \quad 0 \le \phi \le \cos^{-1}\frac{3}{5}, \quad \frac{3}{\cos \phi} \le r \le 5
$$

When I compute the integral with these bounds, I get $128\pi$.

Alternatively, in cylindrical coordinates (easier):

$$
0\le \theta \le 2\pi, \quad 3 \le z \le \sqrt{25-r^2}, \quad 0 \le r \le 4
$$

Again, the integrals equals $128\pi$.

Comment: Thinking about the alternative solution, $z= \sqrt {25-r^2}$ only gives an hemisphere. How can this get the part from $z=3$ to the total sphere?

Comment: @math.h $3 \le z \le \sqrt{25-r^2}$

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find out an alternative solution. I will simply integrate into the cut-off sphere until $\varphi$ makes an angle $cos^{-1}\varphi = 3/5$. This will leave off a cone, which i shall integrate later.

So, $I_1= \int \int \int (2p^3\cos\varphi \sin\varphi)\ d\varphi \ d\theta \ dp $ with the following limits of integration:

$0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi, 0\leq p \leq 5, \cos^{-1}(3/5) \leq \varphi \leq \pi$

gives us the value $-200 \pi$. Since we are considering the unit outer normal, and the integral evaluated consider the outer normal in the oposite way, we have that $I_1= 200 \pi$.

Now we are going to evaluate the integral over the remaining cone. The cone is described by $x^2+y^2 = 16/9z^2$, and hence in terms of cylindrical coordinates we have the integral:

$I_2= \int \int \int 2zr\ \ dr \ dz \ d\theta$ 
with the following limits of integration:

$0\leq \theta \leq2\pi, 0\leq z \leq3, 0\leq r \leq 4/3z  $

which gives us $72\pi$. Thus, with the correct orientation we have $-72\pi$

Adding up $I_1+I_2= 128\pi$, as already find by our friend.